# How to resolve WIFI issues on Arduino YUN

Tags: openwrt, downgrade, arduino-yun

I have recently upgraded the open wrt of my Arduino YUN to version 3.18.23. After the upgrade, I have lost the WIFI access point of the YUN. I have also tried to reset the WIFI using the WIFI reset button but that seems not to work. Moreover, I have also tried to flash it but this has not solved the issue. Is there a way to revert back to the previous version of open-wrt? Downgrading the open-wrt, kernel and bootloader to the previous version more specifically?

Comment: Did you enable your wifi in settings (it is disabled by default)?

Comment: what do you mean by enabling wifi in settings? I cannot access the YUN web panel itself. And i have tried to wifi reset the yun also but i did not work either.

Comment: Can you access it via Ethernet or UART?

Answer (score 0):

The openwrt img doesn't activate wifi by default. To revert, you can use the image provided on the arduino.org website.